# When adding text to a metafile, the letter font is changed

Tags: c#, graphics, drawstring, metafile

I want to add some text to a metafile.
The code i use:

```
Metafile m = new Metafile("1.emf");
Graphics grfxVideo = CreateGraphics();
IntPtr ipHdc = grfxVideo.GetHdc();
Metafile mf = new Metafile("2.emf", ipHdc);
grfxVideo.ReleaseHdc(ipHdc);
grfxVideo.Dispose();
Graphics grfxMetafile = Graphics.FromImage(mf);
grfxMetafile.DrawImage(m, 0, 0);
grfxMetafile.DrawString("test",SystemFonts.DefaultFont,SystemBrushes.Desktop,new PointF(0,0));
grfxMetafile.Dispose();
mf.Dispose();
m.Dispose();
```

The letters at the new metafile (*2.emf*) is more bold than the original emf file.
Also the new metafile is at least twice the size of the original.
What am i doing wrong?

Edit: the original emf file (*1.emf*) is created from an emf spool file and the text  is inside the `ExtTextOutW` and `ExtTextOutA` records.

Comment: Observing pretty much similar behavior which breaks my attempts to use metafiles for caching complicated graphics in my application.